# HY093: Wrong number of parameters - positional

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am getting the HY093 error on the `$q->execute` line.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined'

```
$stmt = "INSERT INTO `survey`(`user`,`notes`,`lat`,`lon`,`acc`,`timestampx`) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$q = sql::$db->prepare($stmt);
var_dump($data);
$q -> execute($data);
```

and my vardump echos:

```
array(6) {
   ["user"]=>string(9) "Your Name"
   ["notes"]=>string(5) "Notes"
   ["lat"]=>string(10) "35.1338614"
   ["lon"]=>string(19) "-106.64091979999999"
   ["acc"]=>string(4) "8512"
   ["time"]=>string(13) "1442043552884"
}
```

When I copy and paste this data into MySQL (replacing the ? with the quoted strings) it works.

Any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: Have you check that your fields type and inserting data type are same? I mean to say is all the fields in table are string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing the two ways of working with PHP. If you want to use an associative array to supply the bind values, your query needs to reference them by name, with a colon (`:`) to indicate these are bind variables:

```
$stmt = "INSERT INTO `survey`" .
        "(`user`,`notes`,`lat`,`lon`,`acc`,`timestampx`) " . 
        "VALUES(:user, :notes, :lat, :lon, :acc, :time)";
```

Alternatively, you could leave `$query` as is and provide the parameters in a simple, positional, array:

```
$data = array("Your Name", 
              "Notes", 
              "35.1338614", 
              "-106.64091979999999", 
              "8512",
              "1442043552884");
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Never would have figured that out. I added a line:

    $data=array_values($data);